# Magento 2 : In IWD one page checkout module how to remove ajax call from city field

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, shipping-address

I am using IWD one page checkout module in Magento 2. I want to remove ajax call to load shipping and payment block on city change. Is it possible to remove Ajax call on city field ?

Comment: I am also using the same Extension but i can see IWD_ALL and IWD_StoreCredit got enabled in admin but not IWD_Opc?
how came you able to install and use the same extension?